# Can I use my ethernet port on my pc as a phone line?

Tags: ethernet, phone, fax, rj-45

I have an ethernet port used for Internet, but since I bought a wireless adapter that port is no longer needed. So I thought instead can I use that port as a phone line and just plug a phone line cable into ethernet port and use the Dialer or Windows fax system by doing that?

Comment: It is possible to use an [IP phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VoIP_phone) this way, but that requires a [VOIP phone service](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=VOIP+phone+service).

Comment: No, even though the connectors look similar (but are different: RJ-11 v.s. RH-45) the signals on the wires are incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***absolutely NOT under no condtion do this!***

The voltages are different and the ring current will fry your NIC.
Although the phone technically only needs 2 wires it there is no way to make this compatible.

DSL and cable both need modems to convert the incoming signals to something the NIC can handle.

https://www.google.com/search?biw=1409&bih=769&tbm=shop&q=usb+modem&oq=usb+modem&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.4069.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0.z0dRvfer_-w

[image: picture of USB modem]
one of dozens of options:
https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/US-Robotics-56K-USB-Fax-Modem/1429761.aspx?cm_cat=GoogleBase&cm_ite=1429761&cm_pla=NA-NA-USR_MO&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=WNvqJAAAAHUR-QoH:20170731165656:s&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqvvLBRDIARIsAMYuvBGjs03vkwEEIKMyrKYbav9tmC_IQ3ORIFOobEIaCdse37CYijc49HkaArXHEALw_wcB&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!198553132239!!!g!317233383341!
You need to get a USB modem.

Comment: Cheers for that, can u list any usb modems?

Comment: @TheGreatScorpio  I provided a link to 1 of them and a second link to google search results of dozens more options.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. Although they look the same at first glance, the Ethernet port will be an RJ-45, whereas a phone port would usually be an RJ-11. They are different sizes and have different numbers of pins (8 and 6 respectively). See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack) for more information.

Furthermore, internally the Ethernet port will be wired into your network interface card (NIC) or its built-in equivalent on your motherboard, which will not know how to make or receive telephone calls on a PSTN (Public Switched Telephone Network) line.